# Switching default gateway based on time

Tags: internet-connection, cron, time, pfsense, pppoe

I've been looking all over for a solution to this.
I have two ADSL PPPoE accounts.
Account A is uncapped during certain hours but has a low "anytime" cap.
Account B has a higher cap but it has a smaller uncapped time window.

Both of them are configured as PPPoE in pfsense(e.g. modem is in bridge mode)

I think the best way to approach this would be via a cron job. I've tried running all the regular commands that I know to change the default gateway (I'm primarily a Linux user), but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that there is a feature called "Firewall Schedule" which allows you to do just this. I can't believe I didn't notice it for such a long time :(

Basically, you need to create a schedule in the Firewall > Schedules section, and then tie certain rules to the schedule. The latter part is close to the end of the advanced options in the edit view for any firewall rule.

Comment: Thanks for closing the loop on your question.  For other people with a similar problem, can you expand at all on the details?